# is the following way also correct for constructor functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor

```js
let construct = function(name = "john", last = "marks") {
  return {
    name: name,
    last: last,
  };
};

let me = new construct("mike", "tyson");
console.log(me);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You do not have a constructor function.**

A constructor function is one you can call with [the keyword `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) in order to produce a new instance of said function. However, yours that just produces plain objects with no inheritance:

Your implementation:

```js
let construct = function(name = "john", last = "marks") {
  return {
    name: name,
    last: last,
  };
};

let me = new construct("mike", "tyson");
console.log(me instanceof construct); //false
```

Proper constructor function:

```js
let construct = function(name = "john", last = "marks") {
  this.name = name;
  this.last = last;
};

let me = new construct("mike", "tyson");
console.log(me instanceof construct); //true
```

This matters if you want to use prototypal inheritance for the produced instances:

```js
let construct = function(name = "john", last = "marks") {
  this.name = name;
  this.last = last;
};

let me = new construct("mike", "tyson");

construct.prototype.fullName = function() {
  return `${this.name} ${this.last}`;
}

console.log(me.fullName()); //"mike tyson"
```

In order to produce proper instances with `new`, it needs to either return nothing (which implicitly produces `undefined`) or return anything other than an object:

```js
function example() {
  this.foo = "bar";
  
  return "this is not an object";
}


console.log(example());
console.log(new example());
```